# cordova-plugin-purchaseで課金を実装したが、sandboxユーザーではうまくいくのに審査ではクラッシュしてしまう

Tags: ios, cordova, アプリ内課金

cordova-plugin-purchaseで課金を実装し、sandboxユーザーでは正常に動作したため審査に提出したのですが、審査員から課金ボタンを押すとクラッシュするという審査結果が届きました。

・審査員からは iPad Pro 、iPad Air でクラッシュを確認したと連絡がありました。
・cordovaを10にアップグレードしても症状は同じでした。
・プラグインをcc.fovea.cordova.purchaseに入れ替えても症状は同じでした。
・審査通過前だからなのか、sandboxユーザーの場合は正常に課金処理できるのですが、通常のAppleIDではAppleStoreに接続できないというエラーが出てしまう。

クラッシュログなどを見ても活用方法が分からず問題解決にいたっておりません。
どなたかお気づきの点があれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いろいろ調査をしたのですが、うまく動作をせず下記のプラグインに変更しました。

cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

Answer (score 0):

この記事はいかがでしょうか？

https://www.glpgs.com/e-blog/archives/191

私もcordovaを利用しているので、その後をお知らせいただけたらありがたいです。

Comment: 単なるリンクだけですと、リンク先のページが削除されてしまった場合に回答の価値が失われてしまいます。どんな点が参考になるのか、要点を引用して回答に含めたりすると、よりよい回答になると思います。

Comment: お返事が遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。最終的にうまく動作しなかったのでプラグインを変えることになりました。